# Android layout I want to see a text and under this text image which fill all empty space

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/button_background_dark_default"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</<LinearLayout
```

but image is over the whole screen and no text is there. I want to see a text and under this text image which fill all empty space. How can i do that?

Comment: nested layouts are a thing you should try to avoid as much as possible because they slow the application a lot. it comes from the fact Android build a tree of the content of a page,and a layout force him to build a second tree inside the first one. for exemple, a relative-layout with only one element inside can easily be removed. in your other ones, you seem to only use bellow, a thing your linearlayout can take care of. it will make your application really much faster to put these off

Comment: after your edit : simplest way to fill blanks with others views aside is to put a weight=1. it is not preponderent over others views,but fill the space left

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? According to me your layout could be simplify with one simple linearLayout with `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="222"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="222ssss"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/button_background_dark_default"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The trick here are these attributs `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. It will tell to android that you want your image to fill all the empty space.

Comment: and he fixed it! you,sir, deserve an acepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should DEFINITLY not use nested linear/relative la yout like that.

anyway, try to put on the relativelayout around the image somthing like above or toleftof ect

EDIT : i didn't see your major layout was linear, then you'll have to use weight=1 on every inside layout,so that they don't priorityse on each other. but using relative layouts for one elements are just making your app slow

Comment: use framelayout instead of relative layout if u want to see the over lapping of the views

Comment: I don't think he wants overlapping views. well, I don't know what he really want,it's not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="222"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="222ssss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"

android:layout_below="@id/rl_1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="222"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="222ssss"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/rl_2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/button_background_dark_default"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it should work I guess, but if you could arrenge his problem with nested relative layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Change the holder of your `ImageView` to a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/button_background_dark_default"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your `RelativeLayout` is expanding because of its `match_parent` content.

Comment: I try but is the same. Image is not over the whole screen.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want. If it's over the whole screen, you won't be able to see any other views. Is this what you want? What do you mean by "after text"? You can't have both "after" and "over"?

Comment: i want to see text and under the text image. Sorry under not over

Comment: So what do you mean by this? "Image is not over the whole screen"? If it is over the whole screen, you will not see text. Please elaborate.

Comment: you're still offering him a solution with nested layouts,which is really not perfect...

Comment: @wazaminator don't be a buzzkill bro :)

Comment: I know by yourself you would have proably not made this,and just try to adapt to his code, but if you can improve the other points,why not?

I believe there is a simple way to get rid of all this nested nightmare